# Vue with TypeScript: declaring components

Tags: typescript, vue.js

When trying to install `vue-class-component` or `vue-class-component` or `vue-property-decorator` I get this error message:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: example@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: vue@3.4.5
npm ERR! node_modules/vue
npm ERR!   vue@"^3.3.11" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer vue@"*" from vue-property-decorator@9.1.2
npm ERR!   node_modules/vue-property-decorator
npm ERR!     vue-property-decorator@"*" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer vue@"^2.0.0" from vue-class-component@7.2.6
npm ERR! node_modules/vue-class-component
npm ERR!   peer vue-class-component@"*" from vue-property-decorator@9.1.2
npm ERR!   node_modules/vue-property-decorator
npm ERR!     vue-property-decorator@"*" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

This is confusing: It says I have `vue@3.4.5`, but that the packages need at least `3.3.11` and `2.0.0`, so they cannot be installed - but "at least" means it should work?

```
<template>
    <p :title="computedText">{{ computedText }}</p>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue } from "vue-property-decorator";

@Component
export default class Example extends Vue {
   private text = 'Hello World!'

   public get computedText(): string { return this.text }
}
</script>
```

I alternatively tried `defineComponent`, which imports successfully, but in the template I cannot access the definitions:

```
<template>
    <p :title="computedText">{{ computedText }}</p>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'

defineComponent({
    data() {
        return {
            text: 'Hello World!'
        }
    },
    computed: {
        computedText(): string { return this.text }
    }
})
</script>
```

In any case, I am very confused about what is the right way to use TypeScript with Vue.

Comment: vue-class-component is for vue 2, that's what it says, it's deprecated. vue-facing-decorator isn't. The right way is to use composition api, which is TS-friendly. Decorators are unofficial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second syntax is right in Vue 3, [for the first one is not recommended by Vue core team since it doesn't go with composition API](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/composition-api-faq.html#relationship-with-class-api).

> We no longer recommend using Class API with Vue 3, given that Composition API provides great TypeScript integration with additional logic reuse and code organization benefits.

As I said the second one is right, but you don't need to declare types explicitely since they are inferred automatically. The computed property should always return something:

```html
<template>
    <p :title="computedText">{{ computedText }}</p>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'

defineComponent({
    data() {
        return {
            text: 'Hello World!'
        }
    },
    computed: {
        computedText(){ //here the computedText has type string inferred
           return this.text;
        }
    }
})
</script>
```

The syntax above is still supported in Vue 3 but it's recommended to use the composition API using script setup :

```html
<template>
    <p :title="computedText">{{ computedText }}</p>
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
import { ref, computed} from 'vue'

const text = ref('Hello World!')

const computedText = computed(()=>text.value)
 
</script>
```

Comment: The missing return in the second example was a typo. Can you put a link to the recommendation in your response to it gets higher in the search results? Because I can't find it. It was the way I did it intially, but every website I found said "no, you should do it this or that way" as shown in the opening post because it's all very outdated.

Comment: Ok I'll add them